# Expression implicitly coerced from 'String? Not printing an optional

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I thought this error was caused when trying to print optionals. I removed the print commands, and I still get the waring. I have screen shotted my code (see attached). Im creating user profile for loving using firebase. Thank you in advance for the help.[image]

Code:

```
func createProfile(_ user: User) {
    let newUser = ["email": user.email,
                    "photo": "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/frostingtest.appspot.com/o/ricks.jpg?
                    alt=media&token=d1f266e0-32aa-465d-bc42-82fdbe84881b"]

    self.databaseRef.child("profile").child(user.uid).updateChildValues(newuser) { (error, ref) in
        if error != nil {
            print(error)
            return
        }
        print("Profile Created Sucessfully")
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The compiler is saying that your `newUser` is a `String?` and your function `updateChildValues` from firebase documentations is : `func updateChildValues(_ values: [AnyHashable : Any])`

Can you print the type of your **newUser variable in your console log ?**

Comment: I had to leave for work. Unfortunately it will be a few hours before I'm back in front of my mac. I'll take a look when I get back. So it looks like I might be using older code then. Thank you.

Comment: The compiler does **not** say *that your `newUser` is a String?*, it says ***Expression** implicitly coerced...*, that means there is one optional value in the object (the keys are clearly non-optional).

Answer (score 0):

First of all this is not an error, it is a **warning**.

If the warning explicitly occurs at `newUser` logically the only possible reason is that `user.email` in the dictionary is an optional.

The compiler suggests the following fixes

1. Assign a default value: `["email": user.email ?? "",...`
2. Force-unwrap the value: `["email": user.email!,...`
3. Explicitly cast to `Any`: `["email": user.email as Any,...`

As you intend to change the email it can be assumed that `user.email` is not `nil` so suggestion 2 is appropriate. If the assumption is wrong suggestion 1 is appropriate because a `nil` value in a dictionary is nonsensical.

---

Unfortunately clicking on the correspondent `Fix` button applies the suggestion misleadingly to `newUser` which could cause a (real red) error. You have to apply the suggestion to `user.email` manually.

Comment: Thanks! I'll give this a try when i get home.